# How to collate the available contemporary press coverage of the 1936 US olympic hockey team?

Tags: historical-research, olympics

This question is essentially asking how to go about searching as many mid-1930s newspapers and magazines as is feasible. I don't even know where to begin. Some major papers that are still in business such as the NYTimes have digitized their archives and put them on the web, but I would guess many haven't fully digitized back that far yet, let alone put the archives up on the web.

I am interested in assembling as many press clippings about the US 1936 Olympic hockey team as possible. I have a budget of perhaps $1,000 USD. I'd be happy to pay an archivist to do the work, if that's an option. I am in DC at the moment and could conceivably access the Library of Congress.

I hope "How to research History" is a valid topic for this site.

Comment: Do you have any kind of institutional affiliations? Access to a university's library system could be very useful here

Comment: I do not presently have access to a university library, unfortunately. As I indicated, I am very willing to pay someone who is good at this sort of thing and does have such access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you haven't found it or tried it yet, you might consider newspapers.com.  The site allows you to search topics, keywords, etc. and look at actual scanned copies of newspapers from past years, going back to the 1700s.  I went to the site and searched ["1936 Olympics Hockey."](http://go.newspapers.com/results.php?query=1936%20Olympics%20Hockey&s_place=&date_field=)  6,363 newspaper matches came back in the results.  The results are broken down further by the newspaper location.  Pennsylvania alone had 1,318 matches.  Of course, with all keyword searches, you'll probably find a lot of articles that aren't relevant to the topic you're researching.  But out of 6,363 results, I'd bet you'll find at least a few contemporary newspaper articles about the 1936 US Olympic hockey team.  The site says you can get a free trial; I don't know what the details are on that.  It also says you can subscribe for a month for $7.95 and for a year for $79.95.  Then you could use the extra $920.05 for something else!  I hope this helps.